# Link to my company tool?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

In review I found [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/71057/6382) to a question:

> Great question!.
>
> Before I answer I just want to let you know that I actually work for MetaVis so my post is a little biased :)
>
> From a MetaVis perspective I can't tell you exactly what to expect as the tool relies on the internet connection that you are using. What I would recommend is downloading & installing MetaVis to figure out the average speed that you will get.
>
> You can get a free trial here http://bit.ly/105Kkfq
>
> Thanks and good luck!

I flagged the answer with a question but I still wonder what policy we have on this kind of links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question ;-)

In my opinion this is a legitimate answer. Firstly the poster gave full disclosure. Secondly the answer was relevant to the question which specifically asked about performance of third party tools such as MetaVis. Thirdly the answer seems helpful to me (depends on your network speed, here's how you can test it at no cost).

After considering the above I handled the flag as "no action required", but thanks for flagging.

Comment: Thanks! Other .SE sites are very strict when it comes to promotion of my own or my company tools, but I agree with your conclusion. Relevant and helpful answer, makes it OK!

Comment: Those people who post an answer that is just an ad for their product against any vaguely related question - that's a problem.

Comment: And as a side remark i already last week deleted all other posts from same user, because no disclosure was given, and contacted offending user about the rules of this site. Also another thing to consider is, that if *all* posts from a given user is answers mentioning their product, it is considered astroturfing. We do have advertising packages for companies that want to create attention on their products

Comment: Good work Anders; looks like they got the message.